# “…to prepare the typhoon” vs. “…to prepare for the typhoon”

Tags: meaning, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

> What do I need to do to **prepare** the typhoon?

vs

> What do I need to do to **prepare for** the typhoon?

Is there any difference between these two sentences?

Can I use “prepare” instead of “prepare for”?

Answer (score 3):

Prepare is a verb that means ‘to make ready for something that may happen’.
If you prepare the typhoon, the typhoon itself is the subject of the verb.
(NOTE: A Typhoon can be a type of military aircraft (in Europe), or a type of submarine (in Russia).)
So ‘prepare the typhoon’ means to make the aircraft ready for something.

In the second sentence, 
“What do I need to do to prepare for the typhoon?”
What we are actually saying is…
“What do I need to do to prepare **myself** for the typhoon”.
‘Myself’ is the thing that is being made ready but by using the phrase ‘**for** the typhoon’ English language allows us to drop ‘myself’ out of the sentence.
The object of the verb is not stated in the sentence but is implied by the use of the preposition ‘for’.

Comment: Except that the Russians themselves call the Typhoon the "Акула" (Akula) meaning "shark".  "Typhoon" is what NATO calls this class of submarine.  So it would be a NATO officer preparing a stolen Russian sub, which sounds like something out of a Tom Clancy novel.  :)

Comment: "What do I need to do to prepare the typhoon?" might be a perfectly sensible sentence in the right context *even when* "typhoon" refers to a type of literal storm.  Should the Atomic Skull obtain a weather control machine from Lex Luthor, I'd be far from surprised if he asked him that question.  Also, in "what do I need to do to prepare for the typhoon," there is nothing that requires the semantic patient to be myself.  I might be interested in preparing myself, or perhaps my family, my home, my boat -- who knows?  Without a direct object, the patient must be inferred.  It's not always me.